# How to save a dictionary within a dictionary in core data

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, core-data, nested

I've set up the following dictionary in my iOS app:

```
cardCollection = ["collectionName": collectionTitle.text, "collectionDescrip": collectionDescription.text, "numberOfCards": newCardGroup.count, "dateCreated": currentDate, "cards": [newCardGroup]]
```

The user creates a number individual cards, which contains text, a date and an uploaded image if the user chooses. This data is put inside a dictionary called `newCardGroup`. Once they're done creating a group of cards, they save this to another dictionary called `cardCollection`.

I've created two entities in the core data model, one with the `newCardGroup` attributes (called Cards) and another with the `cardCollection` ones (called CardCollection). The `CardCollection` entity is set up as the main entity with a `one-to-many relationship` with Cards. However, I'm having trouble with how to save this type of information using the core data model framework. I was hoping to keep it simple, and not have to use a third party storage service like Firebase, but I can't find any examples of saving a dictionary like described above in core data.

Comment: Fetch, update and save again.

Comment: Sharad, can you provide an example of how you'd update/save the info and then fetch? Would you fetch each attribute and add them to a dictionary in the view controller? Or, if you can provide a link to a suitable answer that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Serialize you dictionary if you are not going to use predicates to search inside your dictionary. Fetch Data and de-serialize it and update and agian save.
How are you saving your dictionary in core data ?